# Symplectic notation proof?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism

> Hello I am trying to work through a little proof of the symplectic condition for Hamilton's equations for a classical mechanics course. I am trying to understand the meaning of the relation $\textbf{M}^T\textbf{J}\textbf{M}=\textbf{J}$.

This is what I have so far. 
\begin{equation}
-\textbf{JM}=(\textbf{J})^T(\textbf{M}^{-1})^{-1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{JM}=\textbf{J}(\textbf{M}^{T})^{-1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{M}^T\textbf{JM}=\textbf{J}
\end{equation}

I am essentially just playing around with the rules $-\Omega=\Omega ^{-1}=\Omega ^T$ for both $\textbf{M}$ and $\textbf{J}$ respectively. Is this correct that they both have these properties? Also as a bit of an aside if $\textbf{J}$ is a block matrix what is the significance of the matrix $\textbf{M}$, what is it called?

Comment: This might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition

Comment: As much as I think this is a fine question, by the rules of the site it should probably be on Math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT) $$z^I~=~(q^i,p_i)~\longrightarrow ~(Q^j,P_j)~=~Z^J~=~f^J(z,t),$$
the matrix $$\textbf{M}^J{}_I~:=~\frac{\partial Z^J}{\partial z^I}$$ 
is the [Jacobian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the CT. Here the indices

$$i,j~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\} \quad\text{and}\quad I,J~\in~\{1,\ldots, 2n\}.$$

If the [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) reads

$$ \{z^I,z^J\}_{PB}~=~\textbf{J}^{IJ}~=~\{Z^I,Z^J\}_{PB}, $$

then it follows that

$$ \textbf{M}\textbf{J}\textbf{M}^T~=~\textbf{J}.$$

If $\Omega_{IJ}$ denotes the inverse matrix of $\textbf{J}^{IJ}$, then

$$ \textbf{M}^T\Omega\textbf{M}~=~\Omega.$$

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Machanics.*

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22157/2451

Comment: Correction to the last word in the answer (v1): _Machanics_ should be _Mechanics._